# Converting different registry value types to string?

Tags: c#, registry

im traversing through the registry, taking the values of the keys and storing them as strings. I have discovered there are many different types. Some of these types are causing my filestream writer to fail. Is it possible to convert all of the below into a string form. The actual data value is not important, just the ability to differentiate between different values.

- DWORD
- ExpandString
- Binary (is this just the same as byte[] ?)
- MultiString

-

```
if (String.Compare(SubKey.GetValueKind(v[i]).ToString(), "String") == 0)
{
    String s = SubKey.GetValue(v[i]).ToString();

    RegistryKeyDataValue rkdv = new RegistryKeyDataValue(s); 
    rkdv.incrementNumberOfTimesUsed();
    rkdv.setTypeOfData("S");

    r.addDataValue(rkdv);
    r.setCurrentDataValue(s);

    String hash = "";
    h.setHashData(hash); 

    hash = h.HashString(s);
}
```

I'm having problems later on because i want to write the values to a file and i need to convert all different types to a string.

Comment: Could you please supply the code you are executing?

Answer (score 1):

There already is a decent standard for writing registry values as strings to a file.  In Regedit.exe, use File + Export after selecting a key to see what that looks like.  Documentation is available in this [KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310516).

Comment: i used that several years ago to write a importer, exporter for WindowsCE 3.0

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look into the [Registry.GetValue()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.getvalue.aspx) description. Within the example all of these types are converted into a string.

Comment: That is what im using, but later on when i extract the contents (which i got from the key using getValue()) im getting errors about weird characters being outputted.

One error i had was something to do with unicode character 'u\144' or something?

Comment: @Tom: It's a good idea to include such information in the question so that people know what problem you actually need to have solved.

Comment: Ah sorry, i thought that problem was due to the one i stated in my question, ie unreadable data.